# Unless Vs. If - What's the difference here?

Tags: grammar

Could anyone explain why one is correct and the other is not?

> I’ll lend you my umbrella if you don’t have yours - Okay 
>   I’ll lend you my umbrella unless you have yours - Wrong

What's the difference in these sentences? What to use when?

Comment: Who said it was wrong?  What reasoning did they give?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your sentence is grammatically correct.

Y will happen *unless* X means that **if** X happens, Y will **not** happen.

So It makes perfect sense to form your sentence as you did *grammatically*:

> I’ll lend you my umbrella unless you have yours.

It means that I am going to lend you my umbrella if you have forgotten yours.

The problem with the sentence is that it is hard to imagine how I will force you to borrow my umbrella, so even if you forgot yours, it would still be up to you to borrow mine or not.

Take this example:

> I will beat you unless you give me your lunch money.

Grammatically it is just like your sentence, but this time it makes more sense that I can keep my word.

I will do X, unless you Y only makes sense if X is something that I can actually execute by myself.

You *could* change your sentence a bit as well:

> I will **not** lend you my umbrella, unless you **forgot** yours.

This means that X (I will **not** lend you my umbrella) will **not** happen **if** Y happens (you forgot your umbrella).

So now, if you do **not** have your umbrella, I **will** lend you mine.